# Asp.NET Response.Write() Gone But Still Writing

Tags: asp.net

I'm an ASP.NET noob and have mostly done desktop and middle-ware service development until now.  I apologize in advance for my noobness.

On several of my pages I was using a Response.Write("Data loading....") type of command to give the user some very basic feedback while some datatables are populated with a ton of data.  My issue is, I have removed it from everywhere (yes, it really is gone from everywhere totally) yet it's still appearing in the browser.  Why?

I have done the following but nothing has gotten rid of it:

1. Closed the browser, cleared all cookies/temp files, rebooted my workstation....
2. Recycled the app pool and restarted the site, along with rebooting the server.....

I've done everything that I can think of but it's still showing in the browser.  I'm guessing it's cached somewhere and I would have assumed that everything I did would have cleared it.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but have you recompiled? This has bitten me a couple of times before.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all as I'm not immune to dumb mistakes when I'm loaded on caffeine.  But yes, I recompiled.  I just don't get this at all.  Makes no sense.

Comment: I'd grab the dll that is used for execution, drop it in [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (or some other decompiler) and find your method where the `Write` method is (or was) being called, and see what the decompiled code looks like.  Might need to clean and rebuild your solution?

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple.  See my answer below.  Small overlooked mistake that caused me a lot of stress.  Thanks all for chiming in and helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your help.  I figured it had to be something either really simple (overlooking something basic) or the universe was preparing to be sucked into a black hole.

The site is being deployed to the server using a batch script to do all the labor.  The path of the files to move to the server were hardcoded in the script for some reason so it was copying over the wrong version of the site.  This directly corresponded and occurred as a result of me just having moved (copied) my dev environment to a different folder.

Updated the deploy script.  Correct files are now getting copied.  Resolved. (Geez.)

Thanks again!